# What is the <l:content> tag meaning?

Tags: tags, sapui5

What is the meaning of the `<l:content>` tag in SAPUI5? I know it is about content, but the references to this tag in the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.GridInfo/code) are not making sense to me. Can someone give me use cases for this tag? It is used only on the `<l:Grid>` control?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Grid is the [sap.ui.layout.Grid](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.Grid.html#constructor) .

As you can see that Grid has an aggregation called `content`. The Tag `<l:content>` is placed there to show the interpreter, which aggregation you fill.

That is not the problem in the sap.ui.layout.Grid, since it has only one aggregation, but ...
... imagine you want to use a [sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm.html#constructor).
The SimpleForm has the aggregations `title`and `content`. So to define a title you have to write the tag `<title>` (with the correct prefix, in this case it would be eg. `<f:title>` with `xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.forms"`)

```
<mvc:View xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
  <f:SimpleForm>
    <f:title>some random title</f:title>
    <f:content>
      <!-- any sap.ui.core.Control you like -->
    </f:content>
  </f:SimpleForm>
</mvc:View>
```

And another thing: The aggregation, that is marked with "**(default aggregation)**" (in the case with the Grid it is `content`) you do not have to add the tag.

```
<mvc:View xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
  <f:SimpleForm>
    <f:title>some random title</f:title>
    <!-- any sap.ui.core.Control you like, is is recognized as content -->
  </f:SimpleForm>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: Thanks herrlock! Is there a list where I can check what is the default aggregation of a control? Once I thought the  "[]" besides the aggregation name in the [API Reference documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html) refered to the default aggregation, but the [sap.m.Bar](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Bar.html) control have a "[]" in all of its aggregations. Is there an easy way to find the default one?

Comment: `[]` means the content is an array

Comment: The jsdoc must have changed, the default-aggragation is not visible anymore. I do not know another way how to get it, sorry.

Comment: the default aggragation is still defined, but not in the docs (https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.layout/src/sap/ui/layout/VerticalLayout.js#L47)